# crispy form height does not change

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have this problem with my {{ form|crispy }} it works just fine for one of my view but for the other one the fields are too thin and whatever I so the width does change but the height which I want to increase does not

what should I do?
if I need to post another part of code please let me know

[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5yzQ.jpg)

Thanks in advance

views.py

```html
from django.forms.models import BaseModelForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import post
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from users.models import Profile
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.views import View
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


@login_required()
def new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         form = PostForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
              form.instance.author = request.user
              form.save()
              messages.success(request, f'Post created!')
              return redirect("/")   
           
    else:
         form = PostForm()
    return render(request, "posts/new.html", {"form": form })


class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
     model = post
     fields = ['title','body']

     def form_valid(self, form):
          form.instance.author = self.request.user
          return super().form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```html
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from .models import post



class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = post
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('author',)
        widgets = {
            'body': Textarea()
        }
```

post_form.html (update view)

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}


<div style="font-size: 18px;">
  <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}

      <div style="margin-top: 30px"></div>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
          <legend class="border-bottom mb-4" style="font-size: 25px;">Edit Post</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
          </fieldset>
        
          <div class="form-group">
            <div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Save edits</button>
        </div>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Try `'body': Textarea({rows:4})`